# prolog - create list from facts by criteria

Tags: list, prolog, fact

I'm trying to create list from the facts in SWI-Prolog.
There are amount of exapmles but I don't understand how to create list by **criteria**.
You can see my code below.
Predicate **extract** doesn't work as I expected.

I need:

```
L = [depos(sbr, 3000, 3), depos(psb, 4000, 4), depos(hkb, 5000, 5)]
```

But I get:

```
?- deposit(X), extract(X, 3, 5, Ls).

X = depos(sbr, 3000, 3),
Ls = [depos(sbr, 3000, 3)] ;
X = depos(psb, 4000, 4),
Ls = [depos(psb, 4000, 4)] ;
X = depos(hkb, 5000, 5),
Ls = [depos(hkb, 5000, 5)] ;
false.
```

What do I wrong?

```
% vim: ft=prolog

depos(rsb, 1000, 1).
depos(vtb, 2000, 2).
depos(sbr, 3000, 3).
depos(psb, 4000, 4).
depos(hkb, 5000, 5).
depos(mkb, 6000, 6).

deposit(depos(Bank, Body, Rate)) :- depos(Bank, Body, Rate).

bank(depos(Bank,_,_), Bank).
body(depos(_,Body,_), Body).
rate(depos(_,_,Rate), Rate).

% Usage:
% deposit(X), bank(X, Ba), body(X, Bo), rate(X, Ra).

% Usage: create List from Body
% ?- findall(Bo, depos(Ba, Bo, Ra), L).
% L = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000].

% Usage: create List from Rate
% ?- findall(Ra, depos(Ba, Bo, Ra), L).
% L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

profit(X, Prof) :-
  body(X, Body),
  rate(X, Rate),
  Prof is Body * Rate.

% Usage:
% ?- deposit(X), profit(X, Pro).
% X = depos(rsb, 1000, 1),
% Pro = 1000 ;
% X = depos(vtb, 2000, 2),
% Pro = 4000 ;

critRate(X, From, Before) :-
  rate(X, Rate),
  Rate >= From,
  Rate =< Before.

% Usage:
% ?- deposit(X), critRate(X, 3, 5).
% X = depos(sbr, 3000, 3) ;
% X = depos(psb, 4000, 4) ;
% X = depos(hkb, 5000, 5) ;

critProf(X, From, Before, Prof) :-
  profit(X, Prof),
  Prof >= From,
  Prof =< Before.

% Usage:
% ?- deposit(X), critProf(X, 9000, 25000).
% X = depos(sbr, 3000, 3) ;
% X = depos(psb, 4000, 4) ;
% X = depos(hkb, 5000, 5) ;

% How to create List Ls from deposit with Rate From to Before ???
extract(X, From, Before, Ls) :-
  bagof(X, critRate(X, From, Before), Ls).

% Expected:
% L = [depos(sbr, 3000, 3), depos(psb, 4000, 4), depos(hkb, 5000, 5)]
```

Comment: Since your `From` and `Before` are free variables, they will "bind".

Comment: This is not a discussion site. Your editing of the answer by CapelliC to ask new questions is very wrong. As you are a new user I won't down vote this question at this time, but if you don't follow the guidelines [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) here I will reconsider. I am not a fan of all of the rules here either, but if we all did what we wanted it would be much harder to find answers when we need them.

Answer (score 1):

> I think your problem is related in structuring your code with 'accessors', like these 3

```erlang
bank(depos(Bank,_,_), Bank).
body(depos(_,Body,_), Body).
rate(depos(_,_,Rate), Rate).
```

> and using them in a functional fashion.

*edit by OP*

Can you, please, explain that aspect in more detail? I'm a new in Prolog.
I've read about **accessors** in Bratko and use it without full understanding.
When I can use and when I don't.

> Prolog has a relational data model, so you should rethink your workflow. For instance, simplify extract/4 to extract/3 in this way

```erlang
extract(From, Before, Ls) :-
  bagof(X, (deposit(X),critRate(X, From, Before)), Ls).
```

> and you'll get what you need:

```erlang
?- extract(3, 5, Ls).
Ls = [depos(sbr, 3000, 3), depos(psb, 4000, 4), depos(hkb, 5000, 5)].
```

**That works! Thank you.**

*edit by OP*

I added new predicate for **critProf**

```
extract_prof4(From, Before, Prof, Ls) :-
  bagof(X, (deposit(X), critProf(X, From, Before, Prof)), Ls).
```

and it doesn't work again.

```
?- extract_prof4(3000,25000,P,L).
P = 4000,
L = [depos(vtb, 2000, 2)] ;
P = 9000,
L = [depos(sbr, 3000, 3)] ;
```

BUT if I added another predicates (without Prof as an argument), like this:

```
critProf3(X, From, Before) :-
  profit(X, Prof),
  Prof >= From,
  Prof =< Before.

extract_prof(From, Before, Ls) :-
  bagof(X, (deposit(X), critProf3(X, From, Before)), Ls).
```

they work correctly:

```
?- extract_prof(3000,25000,L).
L = [depos(vtb, 2000, 2), depos(sbr, 3000, 3), depos(psb, 4000, 4), depos(hkb, 5000, 5)].
```

**Why?**

Comment: Why `bagof/3` and not `setof/3`?